# findViewById Android to return multiple results

Tags: android, textview, findviewbyid, linkify

I am have created an android application that incorporates a relativelayout within a scrollview, and had trouble making my links within textview clickable.  To work around this I am using

```
TextView TextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview2);
TextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getinstance());
```

So, I am aware that findViewById() will only ever return the first instance.  What can I do if I were, say, to want textView2, textView4, and textView8 all to become links.  I assume a for loop here will do the trick?

Comment: I don't see the problem.  Wont each of these TextViews have a unique ID?  Thus you simple call findViewById for each one.  e.g.  TextView TextView4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview4);

Comment: `findViewById() will only ever return the first instance`. There is only one instance.  R.id.xxxx is unique.

Comment: with the following line being 'TextView4.setMovementMethod(..)' correct?  I can do this, I will be doing it for about 300 textViews, however

Comment: OK, I see the problem, and why a loop would be beneficial. I have a couple ideas.  I will post an answer in a minute...

Comment: Thank you-- I look forward to seeing it tomorrow morning (headed to the other office for the night)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your above comment that you have hundreds of TextViews, you could try the following:

Assuming a layout of like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="container" ...
   <TextView android:id="tv1" ... />
   <TextView android:id="tv2" ... />
   <TextView android:id="tv3" ... />
    ....
   <TextView android:id="tv300" ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

You could do the following:

```
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
int count = container.getChildCount();
for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    View v = container.getChildAt(i);
    if (v instanceof TextView) {
          TextView tv - (TextView)v;
          tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getinstance());
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like it will work, however, I am not going to need every textView set to a link.  What if not all of my textViews need a link?
More specifically, if I have textview.setMovementMethod(...) on a textview with no link, is this going to throw off my program?  Upvoting anyway, because the answer you have given me is going to work well enough

Comment: In this case, it takes all the children. And like you mentioned, if you know which ones you are going to set as link, not to mention not all of them might be the same type, you can use the solution I posted.

Comment: For example, in you XML layout file use an id of "clickableTextView1", "clickableTextView2", etc.  Then in your Java code, check the ID of the textView and only take action if the ID starts with the string "clickable"

Comment: Yeah.  This will work.  Really your first answer solved this for me.  The difficulty with going through and adding something to the ID for these is that I built the entire thing in relativelayout, aka changing the name of one requires changing it in several other places as well.  But we live and we learn, I think this is the last and only time i will use a relativelayout within a scrollview

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you declare an element or create it, it is highly recommended to specify a unique id, at least if they are going to be within the same ViewGroup.

In xml:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/txtId1" 
...
/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/txtId2" 
...
/>
```

or by calling

> [View.setId(int id)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId(int))

In your case it would be easier to assign those in xml, do so for each of your TextViews.
Once you have those, you can manually add them into an array and loop through them:

Array:

```
int[] viewArray = {R.id.txtId1, R.id.txtId2};
```

Loop:

```
int size = viewArray.length;
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(viewArray[i]);
    if(view != null) {
        view.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getinstance());
    }
}
```

Make sure the above code is in the activity that is inflating you xml. For instance:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);//This xml should contain the TextViews mentioned above.
```

Otherwise, if you are inflating your own view call:

```
myView.findViewById(viewArray[i]);
```

For more info check [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) class documentation.

Comment: This one makes a lot of sense to me, and is exactly what I was looking for.  However, it didn't work.  I did, however, get it to work with a few tweeks.  Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Again make sure you define a unique id in XML for each TextView, then use that same id in the array. I'll change the code to make it more clear.

Comment: If this was in fact the answer for your question make sure to mark it as so.